# Creating a Wire with a custom index range

Tags: chisel

Is it possible to create a Wire in Chisel3 with custom indexing like how it's done in Verilog?

Here's an example of how it can be done in Verilog:

```
wire [7:4] a;
```

I have tried to create an equivalent Chisel3 code with Input wire having custom range as shown in the following code :

```
class cl extends Module{
    val io=IO(new Bundle{
        val in = Input(UInt(range = (7,4)))
        val out = Output(UInt(4.W))
    })
    io.out := io.in
}
```

However I get the following error during compilation :

> [error] (range: (chisel3.internal.firrtl.NumericBound[Int],
>   chisel3.internal.firrtl.NumericBound[Int]))chisel3.core.UInt 
>   [error] (range: chisel3.internal.firrtl.Range)chisel3.core.UInt
>   [error] cannot be applied to (range: (Int, Int))
>   [error]     val in = Input(UInt(range=(7,4)))

Is there a valid syntax for Chisel3 to create a Wire with custom indexing like how it is shown in the Verilog example?

Comment: There is no way in Chisel to do this. Can you expand a bit on the use case?

Comment: One use-case for this would be in the implementation of multipliers. Indexing partial products is faster to do this way and also helps in parameterization. The only other way is to declare wires of larger size and assigning them to zero, which cannot be parameterized and is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Fundamentally you'd be expressing the same logic though right? I don't see why synthesis tools would give you different results. Can you show an example running through synthesis (Yosys preferably, or Xilinx/Altera tools would work too) that illustrates there's any improvement from using custom index ranges?